# HTML/CSS Form (Table) DOB line showing on two lines

Tags: html, css

On my websites form - my date of birth day, month and year menus are showing on two lines, I'd like them to all show on the same line instead.

When I test the code it show's on one line so I believe there must be a width issue.

You can see the issue on the right hand form (incomeprotectionstore.co.uk).

Any help would be much appreciated.

The date of birth css can be seen below:

```
<tr>
          <td nowrap=""><label><div align="left">Date of birth</div></label></td>
        <td><select name="x_C1DOB_YYYY" id="dd_dob_year" class="input-dob">
<?
for($i=1995; $i >= 1900; $i--){ 
?> 
<OPTION value="<? echo $i; ?>" <?  formSelected( $x_C1DOB_YYYY, $i ); ?>><? echo $i; ?></OPTION>
<?
}
?>
          </select>
          <select name="x_C1DOB_MM" id="dd_dob_month" class="input-dob">
  <?
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){ 
 if($i < 10) $x = "0".$i; else $x = $i;

 $month = $month_name[$i-1]; 
?> 
<OPTION value="<? echo $x; ?>" <?  formSelected( $x_C1DOB_MM, $x ); ?>><? echo $month; ?></OPTION>
<?
}
?>
        </select>
          <select name="x_C1DOB_DD" id="dd_dob_day" class="input-dob">
<?
for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){ 
 if($i < 10) $x = "0".$i; else $x = $i;
?> 
<OPTION value="<? echo $x; ?>" <?  formSelected( $x_C1DOB_DD, $x ); ?>><? echo $x; ?></OPTION>
<?
}
?>          </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: The URL is: incomeprotectionstore.co.uk
The CSS can be found at: incomeprotectionstore.co.uk/images/index.css
The Form CSS is found at: incomeprotectionstore.co.uk/form.n1.css

Comment: Code on JSFiddle can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/uALs5/

Comment: The code in your fiddle is broken, since it does not execute PHP. And because some _idi*t_ thought it was a good idea to disable right clicking on the live example page I could not investigate the problem there easily … so you will have to do that on your own. (But the HTML [is a mess](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://incomeprotectionstore.co.uk/), so go fix that first.)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - still seeking a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your selects in an element that prevents line-wrapping like this:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <select>
  <select>
  <select>
</div>
```

Comment: I tired this but couldn't seem to get it to work. I also already have a nowrap element within the <td> please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dz6KP/

Answer (score 0):

Set `width:200px;` on the `<td>` containing the DOB dropdowns (like it is set on the `<input>`s in the rest of the form)

for instance `<td class = "dob-wrapper">` in the HTML and `.dob-wrapper { width:200px; }` in the CSS

**Final answer:**

Change the first `<td>` to `<td style="width:99px;">` Then change the second `<td>` element  to `<td style="width:200px;">`

If you want the boxes on the right instead of left change use 160px instead of 99px

Comment: I changed the <td> to <td width="200px" nowrap=""> however this does not seem to affect the line?

Comment: If you do it directly on the element change it to this: `<td style="width:200px;"> ... </td>`

Comment: I changed the line to: "<td style="width:200px;" td class = "dob-wrapper">" and added the orginal line within the css but it's still showing on two lines?

Comment: Do like this:

Change what is now `<td style="width:200px;" td class = "dob-wrapper">` to `<td style="width:99px;">`

Then change the `<td>` element _after that one_ to `<td style="width:200px;">`

If you want the boxes on the right instead of left change use 160px instead of 99px

Comment: Yes! Thank-you! You are my new favouite Icelander!! Long live active volcanos!

Answer (score 0):

this is the working code of birthday. try this

```
<div id="birthday">
                <p>Birthday</p>
                    <table id="birthday">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <select name="month">
                                    <option value="">Month</option>
                                    <option value="01" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '01') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Jan</option>
                                    <option value="02" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '02') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Feb</option>
                                    <option value="03" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '03') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Mar</option>
                                    <option value="04" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '04') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Apr</option>
                                    <option value="05" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '05') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>May</option>
                                    <option value="06" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '06') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Jun</option>
                                    <option value="07" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '07') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Jul</option>
                                    <option value="08" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '08') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Aug</option>
                                    <option value="09" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '09') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Sep</option>
                                    <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '10') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Oct</option>
                                    <option value="11" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '11') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Nov</option>
                                    <option value="12" <?php if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == '12') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Dec</option>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <select id="day" name="day">
                                    <option value="">Day</option>
                                    <?php
                                    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $i . '"';
                                        if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day'] == $i) 
                                        {
                                            echo ' selected="selected"'; 
                                        } 
                                        echo '>' . $i .  '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <select id="year" name="year">
                                    <option value="">Year</option>
                                    <?php
                                    for($i=2014; $i>=1905; $i--)
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $i . '"';
                                        if(isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] == $i) 
                                        {
                                            echo ' selected="selected"'; 
                                        } 
                                        echo '>' . $i . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>   
                                </select>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
```